# Android RecyclerView Adapter : update already drawn item view in the click listener for current itemview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

So I have a quiz app, in which I present the user with a question and four options. The 4 options are given in a `RecyclerView`, so I am passing the 4 options(as string `ArrayList`) and the correct answer(string) to the `RecyclerView` adapter constructor.
Now if the chosen answer is correct the `itemView` is set to green and if wrong it is set to red(up to this is working fine).

**My problem is that**

> *when I press the wrong answer I have to set the background color of the itemview(already drawn) with correct answer to turn green along
>   with the selected wrong answer turning red*

See my code below

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final OptionsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    viewHolder.tv_name.setText(option.get(i));
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (option.get(i).equals(correct)){
                Toast.makeText(context,"CORRECT ANSWER :)",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.correctAnswer));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context,"SORRY INCORRECT ANSWER :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.wrongAnswer));
            }
        }
    });

}
```

In the above snippet of my `onBindViewHolder`, the arraylist `option` is having the 4 options and the string `correct` is the correct answer.

*How can i turn the correct answer to turn green when the wrong answer clicked?*

Below image shows what iam expecting when wrong answer clicked

[image]

Comment: Update your arraylist after click listener and then call notifyItemChanged(position).

Comment: you need to update your list(option) , follow the comment by Ronak.

Comment: @RonakThakkar infact iam not altering the contents of my arraylist, so why should i call notifyItemChanged(position), can you please elaborate?

Comment: ok thanks @RonakThakkar ,so i need to keep a flag in the model to check if its selected, let me try this

Comment: thanks, the mistake i did was that I used a string arraylist instead of a <model> arraylist as you said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Add These methods to your model class:**

```
private boolean isSelected;

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    isSelected = selected;
}
```

**Add this code `onClick` on your adapter:**

```
if (mArrayList.get(position).isSelected()) {
    mArrayList.get(position).setSelected(false);
} else {
    mArrayList.get(position).setSelected(true);
}
notifyItemChanged(position);
```